# Is it right to teach other people?

Tags: ethics, modern-world, texts, teaching, self

Everyone of us is unique, with different percepts, respective back ground & nature. although Way of living can be equally beneficial to everyone, inhaling & exhaling peace of mind, together. So many religions, text, even our history tell us about us. All these teach us while a few people get elevated level and again start teaching us. 
I've learned a lot from them but the best i learn and adapt that comes within and stay within me IS ACTUALLY RESULT OF MY ABILITY TO BEND MY THINKING. My question is just this simple - is it right to share my thinking with others or not? Aren't we are becoming more dependent on others?

Comment: Hi. Do you mean In general? Or From the buddhist perspective?

Comment: From the buddist perspective, actually.

Comment: I've edited the title to better reflect the content of the question. Please roll back if the title isn't suitable. Metta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How is it right to teach other?

If one's teachings teaches people how to become free from suffering and that teaching deals with ultimate reality then that would be considered wholesome way of acting.

If one teaches freedom from suffering but one's teachings are dealing with concepts such as a Creator God it is not wholesome since it will not lead people to Liberation. It will instead bring more *delusion* into other beings minds and steer them further away from the path to end suffering. Since delusion is what is keeping beings in Samsara it would be considered unwholesome to input more delusion in them.

> Is it right to share my thinking with others or not?

What kind thinking are we talking about?

If one is sharing unwholesome ways of thinking with others that might lead to wrong speech, wrong action.

Another aspect to mention is also whether or not the other being in some way has agreed to be told about one's thoughts. Sometimes a being might have problems in his or her own life and might not have energy to listen to other beings problems. If one then just unloads on that being without that being wanting to listen that might not be a good thing.

In the same way if one has criminal intentions and wants to commit a crime then if one tells another innocent being about ones plans one will actually involve that being in the act. Now that being has some unwanted knowledge which is placing that being in an unfortunate sitation. Should the being go to the police with the information or what to do? These are just examples of what might happen if we share wrong and unwholesome ways of thinking with other beings.

One could also choose to share wholesome thoughts, i.e. thoughts of renunciation, peace, friendliness, loving-kindness and the like. This would be beneficial not only for oneself but also for other beings. One might share an advice with another being who is in need for advice. Wholesome actions will produce wholesome results.

> Aren't we are becoming more dependent on others?

This question is difficult to answer since it can be answered in many different ways. It's actually subjective. Some people will say no while others will say yes. I do not have an answer for this question.

What i would like to point out is the "attachment-factor" in the question. The Buddha clearly stated that we should be our own refuge and not rely on other people for salvation. With that in mind one should strive to set oneself free. One should practice diligently and not be negligent. A human life is very short and we must practice while the body and mind is still intact. Old age, sickness and death will come to all of us.

[See Dhammapada Verse 166 - The Story of Venerable Attadattha](http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/dhammapadatxt1.pdf).

Being dependent on others will not set one free. The Buddha's only show the way. We ourselves must practice it.

May you be well and happy and free from suffering.

Answer (score 1):

Nah, because knowledge is not enough anyway. Even if someone is totally open to learning from you they must be even more eager to put things into practice in order to reach a particular field's skillful attainments.

Buddhism teaches the Middle ground: do enough learning but also do enough practice to achieve one's goal. Don't have too much pride in either knowledge nor practice because knowledge without practice is useless and practice without knowledge is blind.

That being said, if there is something you can share with someone that you think **for sure** would help them, then it is the poison of greed to hold it back!

Anyway, it is most likely that you are wrong because people can find all sorts of ways to ignroe excellent wisdom and intelligence, nothing is perfectly persuasive..

Answer (score 1):

The way it was explained to me is that, similar to what Sri Lanka said, there is a risk of creating more delusion and dukkha if one is teaching while one has not fully attained enlightenment.. ie.  the way to liberation is not transmitted fully. Since I am just a pilgrim on the path of a thousand steps, I can only offer my own experience in support of other's paths.

Some people teach for the joy of it, some people for the ego gratification it supplies. I've always thought of buddhism as being about the 'doing' and not so much the 'talking'. So for me, I'd rather practice with others than try to 'teach' them about it...